# Anaconda 3 installation - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda

Currently I am trying to install Anaconda 3 on Windows 10. The installation runs mostly fine up until the post installation phase, where it throws the error 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'.

[Here is the full error message, which I'm not going to type here.](https://gyazo.com/9a24c64ff3c46da878cabc4e0270ab49) Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: From what source do you install?

Comment: I am installing with the Windows graphical installer (64-bit) from the Anaconda website.

Comment: Did you ensure that you downloaded the proper Anaconda for the python version you want (python 2 or python 3)?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely the correct version for Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the follwing steps to install anaconda:

Choose the required version 64/32 bit version and download the exe from: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section

Note: Check if your machine is **32 or 64 bit before installing**

Also, while navigating through the installation steps, make sure you add Anaconda to your PATH variable. (Shown [image])

Click Install.

Comment: I did try this several times, but it still gets the same error. A stupid question, but Anaconda comes with Python doesn't it? It doesn't need to be a serperate download?

Comment: Yes. Anaconda comes with Python. No separate installation is required.